# How to run Qt Android application as superuser?

Tags: android, qt, qtserialport, superuser

I'm using qserialport on my android app and the debugging information shows me that it can't create lock file (permission denied), then opening serial has failed. I need to run my app as superuser  on Android to fix this permission problem.